# php controller doesn't load css file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working in a project with my own MVC php, I get the controller and the method to be called from the url,  it calls the right controller and the right method but it doesn't load the css and javascript code.

For example when I go to mysite/public/home/index
It calls the controller home and the method index. But it tries to load the css  from mysite/public/home/css/mystyle.css and my css  are in mysite/public/css/mystyle.css

This is my directory
[Directory Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2MRh.jpg)

```
// this is my index.php in the public folder

<?php

require_once "../app/init.php";
$app = new app();

//this is my app class in core
class app
{
    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();
        if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
            echo $this->controller . "/";
        }
        require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';
        $this->controller = new $this->controller();
        if (isset($url[1])) {
            if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            } else {
                echo $this->method;
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }
        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : [];
        call_user_func([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function parseUrl()
    {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            return explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], "/"),
                FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}

//this is my class controller in core
class Controllers
{
    public function view($page)
    {
        require_once '../app/views/' . $page . '.php';
    }

    public function model($model)
    {
        require_once '../app/models/' . $model . '.php';
    }
}

//this is my controller home
class Home extends Controllers
{
    public static function index()
    {
        $this->view('home');
    }


}
//this is the code where I embed the css/jss it's located in the view called home

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>ChatMe-Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
</head>
//this is the htaccess file
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /facebook/public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. We can’t run your screenshot as code.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Hi! I just post it

Comment: Show us the code with which you embed the css/js file(s) and specify its location.

Comment: Please also post the relevant parts of your .htaccess (all the RewriteRules you must have in there)

Comment: I just did, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/mystyle.css">
```

Comment: It doesnt wotk, the problem is that is trying to load it from a folder call like the method and that doesnt even exist

Comment: Can you share the source of your HEAD section ( the place where you build it ... ) ?

Comment: I just did, Thanks